# How to pass the page object instance between it blocks in nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I am using "BDD describe" to write my ui test in nightwatch. One of the issue i am encountering is , I couldn't use the same page object instance between the "it" blocks. I have to repeat the same line of code in each "it" block to get the test run. 
i am repeating below code

```
const loginTest = browser.page.loginPage();
```

I there any way to avoid the redundancy ? . Here is my test. Please note nightwatch is not allowing me to create the instance under describe block.

```
describe('Login Cases', function() {

beforeEach (browser => browser.url(browser.launchUrl)

it('Verify login is successful', async function (browser) {

  const loginTest = browser.page.loginPage();

  await loginTest.waitForElementVisible('@body')
  await loginTest.setValue('@emailInput',browser.globals.Username)
  await loginTest.setValue('@passwordInput',browser.globals.Password)
  await loginTest.click('@submitBtn')
  await loginTest.expect.element('@myAccountBtn').to.be.visible;
});

it('Verify incorrect login', async function (browser) {

  const loginTest = browser.page.loginPage();

  await loginTest.waitForElementVisible('@body')
  await loginTest.setValue('@emailInput','incorrectusername')
  await loginTest.setValue('@passwordInput','incorrectpwd')
  await loginTest.click('@submitBtn')
  await loginTest.expect.element('@myAccountBtn').to.not.be.present;
});

   afterEach (browser => browser.end());
});

This is how i wrote for before block to instantiate the login page object.  
its returning loginTest is not defined.  

beforeEach(async function(browser) {
const loginTest = browser.page.loginPage();
browser => browser.url(browser.launchUrl)
```

});

I solved the problem by using this keyword when i instantiate the page object.

```
beforeEach(async function(browser) {
  this.loginTest = await browser.page.loginPage()
  await this.loginTest.loginSuccess(browser.globals.Username,browser.globals.Password)
  this.myAccounttest = await browser.page.myAccountPage();
});
```

Comment: Then add the `loginTest` initialization at the end of the `beforeEach` (_last statement_).

Comment: Also for: _Please note nightwatch is not allowing me to create the instance under describe block._ Why? What error are you getting in the console. Update question with that too.

Comment: This is how I tried under describe.   i am getting browser is not defined                                                                                                         
  `code`                                                                                          
   describe('Login Cases', function(browser)                                                            
   {
     const loginTest = browser.page.loginPage();                                                                       
   }

Comment: Did you pass it the `browser` object like in your it-statements: `describe('Login Cases', function(browser) {`? Also, in `beforeEach`, use it there, should work.

Comment: please check my main post. I have added my before block passing with browser object. its returning LoginTest is not defined.

Comment: any comments for this problem will be very helpful to solve this issue.

Comment: I actually figured out. I have to use this keyword  and it works brilliantly. It is in the documentation as well.   please check the main post

Comment: please find the link below as well - https://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-bdd-describe-beta-

Answer (score 0):

```
 beforeEach(async function(browser) {
  this.loginTest = await browser.page.loginPage()
  await this.loginTest.loginSuccess(browser.globals.Username,browser.globals.Password)
  this.myAccounttest = await browser.page.myAccountPage();
});
```

using the **this** keyword when we initiate the page object solves the issue.

Detail documentation can be find here - https://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-bdd-describe-beta-